# Seoul (Incheon) airport transit

Tags: transit, icn, uzbek-citizens

We are flying to Tokyo through Seoul’s ICN airport. We are Uzbekistan ciitizens and flying from Tashkent airport. We have 2 different airlines. Uzbekistan airlines (HY 511) and Jin Air (LJ 203) with 6 hours layover. As these airlines are separately booked I was told we can’t get our luggage at ICN as we can’t get out of the transit zone?

Any suggestions / recommendations please?

Comment: Any suggestions for what? How to get your luggage? What to do for six hours?

Comment: Sorry. How to claim my luggage in transit zone and check in for different airline?

Comment: Your luggage will be tagged for Seoul and sent to the baggage claim there. You will have to claim it and pass through customs and immigration to check it in for your next flight. As Uzbeks you will need a visa for this. I found one post on TripAdvisor that suggested you could claim baggage and check it in again within the transit area, but I haven't been able to corroborate it.

Comment: What if we book Seoul Tour? Will it possibly take us out of the transit zone and I can get my luggage? Or still we need a visa ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've booked separate tickets for the two legs of your journey from Tashkent to Tokyo then the airlines won't automatically transfer your baggage from one flight to the next. You'll need to reclaim your bags and check them in for the next flight. This will require you to pass through immigration<sup>*</sup>.

As Uzbeks you will need a visa at Incheon airport to enter Korea.

You asked if booking the tour will allow you to get to your bags. If the tour was 'airside only' then it wouldn't. However, the tour does allow you access to the places, restaurants and shops, but to do this you have to enter Korea by passing through immigration and that requires you to have a visa. The tour won't help you.

You could ask Uzbekistan Airlines if there's some way that they can transfer your bags for you. If there is, they may charge you for the service.

Otherwise, you'll need a visa.

<sup>* I found one post on TripAdvisor that suggested you can claim and re-check your bags in the transit area, but I haven't been able to corroborate it.</sup>

Comment: Can you provide a source for that visa requirement? I was under the impression that ICN allows anybody with a flight connecting in less than 24 hours to enter.

Comment: @jpatokal From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea): In general, travelers in transit do not require a visa to transit through South Korea for less than 24 hours (for Incheon Airport) or when departing on the same calendar day (for all other airports) __as long as they stay within the transit area.__ (my emphasis).